# Updating counter of picked objects from a list

Tags: netlogo

I would like to update the counter of an element in a list, every time it is picked from turtles. 
To do that, I am setting the item I am interested in and adding 1 to it (counter). 
I created a global variable called `it_cnt` and I set it equal to `0` in the `hatch` where I create the objects (in order to know which turtle owns that item initially).

This is where I initialise the counter:

```
ask buyers [
hatch-obj random 5 [
            set it_cnt 0
        ]
]
```

Please see below the list that I am considering

```
let picked_obj (list item 0 obj_in_shop_bag item 1 obj_in_shop_bag item 2 obj_in_shop_bag item 3 obj_in_shop_bag)
```

I am updating the counter as follows

```
let new_id_cnt item 3 picked_obj + 1
```

to add `1` in case the `picked_obj` is chosen by a buyer. However, when I print the list to see if it works

```
print (word " ; " item 0 obj_in_shop_bag " ; " item 1 obj_in_shop_bag " ; " item 2 obj_in_shop_bag " ; " item 3 new_id_cnt)
```

if the item is picked twice from different buyers in different ticks (ticks are `item 0` in the list), the only value that I get is `1`, as it was reset.

I would greatly appreciate if you could tell me how to fix the counter in order to let it work correctly.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer but is too long for comments. I can't make sense of the question.

You have `set it_cnt 0` in the `hatch` but you say it's a global variable. So if you have 10 buyers, each of them hatches 0 to 4 obj and that single copy of the global variable is set to the value 0 by every one of the potentially 40 objs. Why? Do you mean that it's a turtle variable that is owned by obj?

Where you are updating the counter, you have suddenly switched the name from it_cnt to new_id_cnt. That won't update anything, there is no connection shown between the values of these two variables.

Comment: I still have no idea how your code is supposed to work, you haven't included anything about updating the counter. What I strongly suggest you do is put lots of `print it_cnt` and similar statements wherever you create or update a counter. This will soon show you why it's not working because the printout will be different than you expect.